# my other require once php page gets error when i call it in index

Tags: php, require-once

I get this error when I try to call product_class.php in index.php. My product_class.php works fine, but when I try to add it to index this error show up:

**Warning: require_once(../Includes/config/general.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Programming\Web\xampp\htdocs\android-api\product\product_class.php on line 2**

**Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../Includes/config/general.php' (include_path='D:\Programming\Web\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\Programming\Web\xampp\htdocs\android-api\product\product_class.php on line 2**

here my code at index.php

```
<?php

require_once('product/product_class.php');
require_once('Includes/config/general.php');
require_once INCLUDES_DIR.'/database.php';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specify the correct file path. If the index.php file and the product or Includes folder are in the same folder, try this:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/product/product_class.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/Includes/config/general.php';
```